# How to run a void function in the background

Tags: visual-c++

I have created a windows form application (CLR Project). When i click the start button, a void function with while loop runs. But the problem is the windows form becomes non-responsive (Not Responding). What I want to do is I want to run the function in the background when the button is clicked and make it stop with a click too and be able to use the windows form. Please help.

My code looks like this:

```
bool isStarting = false;

btnStart_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^  e){
   if(isStarting){
      isStarting = false;
   }else{
      isStarting = true;
      runCode(param1, param2, param3);
   }
}

void runCode(param1, param2, param3){
   while(isStarting){
      //do something
   }
}
```

Comment: please try sth to use `thread`.

Answer (score 0):

`Not Responding` occurs when program fall into **infinite loop**.

In your program, you used infinite loop in `runCode` method.

This will be fixed when you use `thread` for `infinite loop` or else.

So I suggest you to use `thread`.

Comment: im sorry but can you edit my code with thread pls? im still new to visual c++ and i've search about thread it really confuses me :D sorry